# R comparing, merge, match dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. One is a template that includes all rows I need. I need all the combinations of sport and model. The other is the output I receive which includes some extraneous rows and is missing others. How do I merge them so that the output dataframe contains all the rows matching (drops unnecessary rows in output and picks up other need rows from the template). I would like the final dataframe to have the average and amount from the output except on those rows that did not exist in which case they should be NA.

Template

```
          date  gender licen checked    sport  model average amount
1  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1 baseball model1      NA     NA
2  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1   soccer model1      NA     NA
3  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1 football model1      NA     NA
4  3/21/16   Woman  CERT       1 baseball model2      NA     NA
5  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1   soccer model2      NA     NA
6  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1 football model2      NA     NA
7  3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 baseball model3      NA     NA
8  3/21/16 Unknown    NO       1   soccer model3      NA     NA
9  3/21/16 Unknown    NO       1 football model3      NA     NA
10 3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 baseball model4      NA     NA
11 3/21/16   Woman    NO       1   soccer model4      NA     NA
12 3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 football model4      NA     NA
```

Output:

```
      date  gender licen checked    sport  model average amount
1  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1 baseball model1     1.2     12
2  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1   soccer model1     4.1     56
3  3/21/16   Woman  CERT       1  walking model2     6.5     33
4  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1   soccer model2     2.4     91
5  3/21/16     Man  CERT       1 football model2     1.1     14
6  3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 baseball model3     3.7     56
7  3/21/16 Unknown    NO       1  running model3     6.1     29
8  3/21/16 Unknown    NO       1 football model3     1.0     17
9  3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 baseball model4     1.6     56
10 3/21/16   Woman    NO       1 football model4     2.7     32
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy pasted your data into `read.table` function:

```
a <- read.table("clipboard", header = T) #Template
b <- read.table("clipboard", header = T) #Output
```

You can use the `merge` function, but you need an unique identifier. Build one with `interaction`. `Paste` would work here as well.

```
a$id <- interaction(a$sport, a$model)
b$id <- interaction(b$sport, b$model)
```

Merge the data, and add all non matching cases in the template df.

```
merge(a, b, by="id", all.x = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work, assuming sport-model combinations are unique in Template:

```
# Drop NA answers
NewData <- Template[, -which(names(Template %in% c("average", "amount")))]

# merge on other data.frame
newData <- merge(newData, Output, by=c("sport", "model"), all.x=T)
```